# How say Not considered enough

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm an English beginner,

I'm looking for single word to convey "there was no enough consideration".

Example:

**Little or no consideration**

There is not enough consideration for the Tablet site as a valuable platform.

So here looking an alternative for the heading - **Little or no consideration**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ***Rushed? Hurried? Precipitate? Impetuous?*** What *kind* of "consideration? By who, in what context?

Comment: *the Tablet site **has been overlooked** as a valuable platform*

Comment: idiom: *dismiss out of hand* (reject without due consideration)

Answer (score 3):

[Cursory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cursory): rapidly and often superficially performed or produced

[Perfunctory](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perfunctory): done quickly, without taking care or interest